# What are famous datasets for semantic scene labeling recorded by drones?

Tags: computer-vision

I'm looking for a dataset to do semantic scene labeling. I know that for indoor scenes there is `NYU Depth v2`. I also found some datasets recorded from a driving car in an outdoor setting. However I'm looking rather for a outdoor dataset that is recorded by a flying vehicle (drone). Does anyone have an idea?

(I apologize if this is not the right place to ask this question, but I couldn't find a better suited one in the jungle of subforums :-/ )

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for RGB Images or Pointclouds, I used the [senseFly](https://www.sensefly.com/drones/example-datasets.html) datasets in one of my works. They have good sets of `RGB geotagged images` that are open to download with some differences in `Resolution, Distance to ground, flight height and locations`. So you can compare your work in different sets and see which is the best scenario and then improve...